# Could the ViewportControl support on windows phone 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, nuget, windows-phone-8.1, nuget-package

Now, I want zoom in or out the picture on listviews. The people had share to me that these question but It use ViewportControl that windows phone 8.1 is not support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ViewportControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.controls.primitives.viewportcontrol(v=vs.105).aspx) is supported for Silverlight 8.1 apps. It is not supported for Windows Phone Runtime apps.

You can use a ScrollViewer to allow a picture to zoom in or out:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              ZoomMode="Enabled" MinZoomFactor="0.7">
    <Grid Height="200" Width="300">
        <Image AutomationProperties.Name="Cute kitten picture" Source="Assets/gracie.jpg" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Or you can handle manipulation events to zoom the picture directly.

```
<Image AutomationProperties.Name="Cute kitten picture" Source="Assets/gracie.jpg" 
       Stretch="Uniform"
       ManipulationMode="Scale"
       ManipulationDelta="Image_ManipulationDelta" 
       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform />
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

C#

```
double minScale = 0.7;
private void Image_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = sender as Image;
    CompositeTransform ct = img.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;

    ct.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
    ct.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;

    if (ct.ScaleX < minScale) ct.ScaleX = minScale;
    if (ct.ScaleY < minScale) ct.ScaleY = minScale;
}
```

See the [XAML scrolling, panning, and zooming sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/xaml-scrollviewer-pan-and-949d29e9) to demonstrate zooming with a ScrollViewer.

See [Quickstart: Touch input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465387#using_manipulation_events) for more info on handling manipulations.

Comment: Hi, I have add one question. When had zoom in but not move and lost  items listview that just show 1 file images.