# What is ViewportControl in Windows Phone 8.1 RT?

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am converting an app from Windows Phone Silverlight to RT, this app can zoom image and it use ViewportControl for this function, but when I used this control on XAML Page of Windows Phone 8.1 RT, there is no control has that name. Does Microsoft provides any replacement for this control, thanks a lot!

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154318/could-the-viewportcontrol-support-on-windows-phone-8-1

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154318/could-the-viewportcontrol-support-on-windows-phone-8-1

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the `ScollViewer`. In the Windows Runtime it has more options then the Silverlight one. Use the `ViewChanged` to get the offsets and modify the position by using `ChangeView()`